# How do I connect to an Azure Service Bus in Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, azureservicebus

Is there any way that I can connect my Flutter Desktop app to an Azure Service Bus with a simple connection string? I could not find any packages about this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want desktop apps to connect directly to Azure Service Bus? How many instances you estimate will be running? Is this internal to an organization app or public? Yes, there's an angle to my questions 

Comment: Yes that is the case. It is going to be an internal app, not public. There will be probably around 4-5 open instances of this application that connects to this Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a Google language there's no SDK for that Azure Service Bus provides. If Flutter Desktop can interop with JavaScript, you could use the [JavaScript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/service-bus?view=azure-node-latest#libraries-for-data-access).

Usually, I would not recommend embedding the connection string in the client application. Rather, pass the connection string from a service/API when the user is authenticated. Depending on your scenario you'll have to decide if there are risks of leaking the connection string or challenges to update it if the key is rotated.